# centos: error named no module lnamed “_repo” came out in

Tags: centos, yum

when I use yum to install a package in centos, the error No module named  '_repo' came out, what should I do to fix it?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

well, there is not much info in the question. but still, I will try to provide you some tricks and solution,

first, find which package provides '_repo'

```
yum whatprovides _repo
```

install the dependency first (here it is _repo)

```
yum install _repo
```

if yum throws an error, use following command to rebuild the yum cache,

```
yum clean all

yum makecache fast
```

and then try 1 and 2 points again.